# Selenium css selector for button text

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

HTML looks like below :

```
<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit">Sign in</button>
```

There are multiple buttons with same class and type value. However I need to click only Sign in button using CSS selector. I tried the following but none of them is working

```
@FindBy(how=How.CSS, using="button:contains('Sign in')") WebElement signInButton;

@FindBy(how=How.CSS, using=".btn btn-primary pull-right[text='Sign in']") WebElement signInButton;
```

Also point me to some complex CSS selector examples site.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A CSS selector doesn't support text evaluation. Use an XPath instead:

```
@FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="//button[text()='Sign in']")
WebElement signInButton;
```

Comment: Note that if the text is not a direct child of the button it won't match, e.g. `<button><span>Sign in</span></button>` won't match.  Instead you can use the xpath `//button[contains(., 'Sign in')]`

Answer (score -1):

Hi plz do it like below considering that your sign in button is first in the list (if not plz change as per your requirement)

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".btn.btn-primary.pull-right")).get(0).click();
```